# Stylesheet not applying in Firefox, but works in Chrome/IE?

Tags: html, css, firefox

Okay, so I'm working on a fairly simple site for a client, and I use the code:

```
<link href="http://ads.jakelee.co.uk/images/default.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css">
```

To reference a stylesheet. Now, this works as expected in Chrome 9, and IE6-8. However, in firefox, no stylesheet appears.

The site itself is [here.](http://ads.jakelee.co.uk)

My question is, how can I make sure the stylesheet applies in firefox too? For reference, I'm using Firefox v3.5.16, released 9th Dec 2010.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try closing the tag <link href="http://ads.jakelee.co.uk/images/default.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" />

Comment: I just opened it with Firefox and it works fine. I am using version 3.6.13.

Comment: Works in my Firefox. Are you sure you didn't disable stylesheets in Firefox? `View` > `Page Style` > `No Style`

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure, other sites function perfectly. I'll try closing the stylesheet, although I've never known this to cause an issue. Anyway, so long as it works for others, I guess that's fine for now. I'm a native chrome user anyway. Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you got the AdBlock Plus extension installed?  I'm subscribed to the EasyList set of filters, and this rule blocks your stylesheet:

```
|http://ads.$domain=~ads.su|~ahds.ac.uk
```

Either remove the rule, or disable ABP on your domain.

Comment: Ah, yes. As I never use firefox, I totally forgot mine came bundled with ABP. I feel **slightly** idiotic now. Thanks!